# What is a valid use case for using TIME WITH TIME ZONE?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, datatypes, timezone, time

Along the lines of this related question:

- [What is a valid use case for using TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59006/what-is-a-valid-use-case-for-using-timestamp-without-time-zone)

Are there any valid use cases for actually using  **`TIME WITH TIME ZONE`** or should it be considered an anti-pattern?

To be clear: I am asking about **`TIME…`**, not **`TIMESTAMP…`**.

Comment: For the record, I've tried to find a reasonable use-case for the Java `java.time.OffsetTime` data type, which corresponds to the SQL `TIME WITH TIME ZONE` type. I couldn't find anything reasonable, [this includes the comments from the library author](https://twitter.com/lukaseder/status/914553994911068161)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is **no valid use case**. `time with time zone` is broken by design and only included in Postgres since it's in the SQL standard. Don't use it.

Time zones can have daylight saving time (DST) rules, which do not work with `timetz` at all.

[In fact, the use of `time with time zone` is officially discouraged:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html)

> The type `time with time zone` is defined by the SQL standard, but the
>   definition exhibits properties which lead to questionable usefulness.
>   In most cases, a combination of `date`, `time`, `timestamp without time zone`,
>   and `timestamp with time zone` should provide a complete range of
>   date/time functionality required by any application.

Comment: Yea, I was going answer along the same lines I wanted to show it was broken by design but it was remarkably hard to demonstrate it.